# Profiling Django

Tags: django, profiling

My django application has become painfully slow on the production. Probably it is due to some complex or unindexed queries.

Is there any django-ish way to profile my application?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try the  [**Django Debug Toolbar**](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). It will show you what queries are executed on each page and how much time they take. It's a really useful, powerful and easy to use tool.

Also, read recommendations about Django performance in [Database access optimization](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/) from the documentation.

And [Django performance tips](http://jacobian.org/writing/django-performance-tips/) by 
Jacob Kaplan-Moss.

Comment: Watch out for Django Debug Toolbar - I turned it off during development and page rendering was significantly quicker on my (admittedly low-power) laptop - look in the dev server to see how much data you're downloading.

Comment: django-debug-toolbar helps me to see how many queries django-orm hits the db, and we can see how select_related() function do the trick hitting it less.

Comment: @dominic-rodger I didn't realize how much slower the Debug Toolbar made things process. My sql queries were small (30ms) but cpu time was very high (800ms). Another page i was tuning had sql times of 300ms, and cpu time of 8000ms - so i kept trying to find the source of the problem. Turning Django Toolbar off sped things right up. 3 years later, still relevant.

Comment: @Esteban, thanks a lot for this comment, i was literally going nuts over the ridiculously high amount of CPU time, dhango toolbar took. With django profiling the CPU time was around 30 seconds, once i removed it, it came down to 1.5 seconds !!

Answer (score 29):

Just type "django-profiling" on google, you'll get these links (and more):

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango

http://code.google.com/p/django-profiling/

http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/django-profiling-hotshot-and-kcachegrind/

Personally I'm using the middleware approach - i.e. each user can toggle a "profiling" flag stored in a session, and if my profiling middleware notices that a flag has been set, it uses Python's [hotshot](http://docs.python.org/library/hotshot.html) module like this:

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):

     # setup things here, along with: settings.DEBUG=True 
     # to get a SQL dump in connection.queries

     profiler = hotshot.Profile(fname)
     response = profiler.runcall(view_func, request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
     profiler.close()

     # process results

     return response
```

EDIT: For profiling SQL queries http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar mentioned by Konstantin is a nice thing - but if your queries are really slow (probably because there are hundreds or thousands of them), then you'll be waiting insane amount of time until it gets loaded into a browser - and then it'll be hard to browse due to slowness. Also, django-debug-toolbar is by design unable to give useful insight into the internals of AJAX requests.

EDIT2: [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) has a great profiling command built in:

https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/docs/runprofileserver.rst

Just do this and voila:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/my-profile-data
$ ./manage.py runprofileserver --kcachegrind --prof-path=/tmp/my-profile-data
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/django-profile/ is a User Profile django application. it's not used as profiling django :)

Comment: @dzen: Hah, good point, it was meant to be: http://code.google.com/p/django-profiling/ :-)

Comment: if you wonder how to read the profiler dumps after running `python manage.py runprofileserver --prof-path=/path/to/dir`, follow this blog: http://www.darkcoding.net/software/profiling-django-for-cpu-bound-apps/.

Comment: ah yes, my favorite, using google to find one of the top answers to my query is "just google the thing you googled to get here"

Comment: Note that `hotshot` has been deprecated and removed in Python 3, so this answer and the `ProfilingDjango` Wiki page may no longer be relevant in 20202.

Answer (score 17):

Shameless plug here, but I recently made https://github.com/django-silk/silk for this purpose. It's somewhat similar to django toolbar but with history, code profiling and more fine grained control over everything.

Comment: Getting middleware issue 'No handlers could be found for logger "silk.middleware"'

Comment: [Profiling is currently broken for many users](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk/issues/269)

Answer (score 15):

For profiling data access (which is where the bottleneck is most of the time) check out [django-live-profiler](https://github.com/InviteBox/django-live-profiler). Unlike Django Debug Toolbar it collects data across all requests simultaneously and you can run it in production without too much performance overhead or exposing your app internals.

[image: Check out this screenshot]

Comment: not support 1.6 and above, no activity for more than a year.

Answer (score 11):

I needed to profile a Django app recently and tried many of these suggestions. **I ended up using [pyinstrument](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstrument/) instead**, which [can be added to a Django app using a single update to the middleware list](https://pyinstrument.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#profile-a-web-request-in-django) and provides a stack-based view of the timings.

Quick summary of my experience with some other tools:

- [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) is great if you the issue is due to SQL queries and works well in combination with `pyinstrument`
- [django-silk](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk) works well, but requires adding a context manager or decorator to each part of the stack where you want sub-request timings. It also provides an easy way to access `cProfile` timings and automatically displays ajax timings, both of which can be really helpful.
- [djdt-flamegraph](https://github.com/23andMe/djdt-flamegraph) looked promising, but the page never actually rendered on my system.

Compared to the other tools I tried, `pyinstrument` was dramatically easier to install and to use.

Comment: +1 on the pyinstrument recommendation! like you said: super useful, fast to install and very clear profiling data. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For all you KCacheGrind fans, I find it's very easy to use the shell in tandem with Django's fantastic test `Client` for generating profile logs on-the-fly, especially in production. I've used this technique now on several occasions because it has a light touch — no pesky middleware or third-party Django applications are required!

For example, to profile a particular view that seems to be running slow, you could crack open the shell and type this code:

```
from django.test import Client
import hotshot

c = Client()
profiler = hotshot.Profile("yourprofile.prof")  # saves a logfile to your pwd
profiler.runcall(c.get, "/pattern/matching/your/view/")
profiler.close()
```

To visualize the resulting log, I've used hotshot2cachegrind:

- http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/ContribPython.html

But there are other options as well:

- http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/
- https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango

Answer (score 4):

When the views are not HTML, for example JSON, use simple middleware methods for profiling.

Here are a couple examples:

https://gist.github.com/1229685 - capture all sql calls went into the view

https://gist.github.com/1229681 - profile all method calls used to create the view

Answer (score 2):

You can use [line_profiler](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler).

It allows to display a line-by-line analysis of your code with the time alongside of each line (When a line is hit several times, the time is summed up also).

[image]

It's used with not-Django python code but there's a little trick to use it on Django in fact: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68163807/1937033

Answer (score 1):

I am using silk for live profiling and inspection of Django application. This is a great tool. You can have a look on it.

> https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk