# How to profile django application with respect to execution time?

Tags: python, django, performance, cpu-speed, django-debug-toolbar

My Django application is insanely slow, I want to figure out what is taking time :

I tried `Django-debug-toolbar` but was unable to find a panel that can give me the break-up of the load time.

My requirements:

- A stack-trace type output with time of execution for each  module called to render the page.
- I want to realize what part of the whole page rendering process is taking the time ?
- Also, what part is consuming how much CPU [ MOST IMPORTANT ] ?

**Can `django-debug-toolbar` do that ? [ What panel ? ]**

**Any other django-app that can do that ?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361985/profiling-django

Comment: @Ahsan That suggested `Django-debug-toolbar` which doesn't serves my purpose as is !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally figured out a way to profile my django webapp :

Following 2 django snippets provide `middleware` that profile the whole flow and outputs if 
request has `prof` in `GET keys` :

- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/727/ [ Uses cProfile ]
- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/186/ [ Uses hotshot ]

Plain and simple profiling - Saved my day !

Comment: Thank you. This has got the be one the most valuable tips I've seen in a long time. It's so simple, I can't believe I have been writing Django apps without profiling.

Comment: Can you please explain how to configure it? just to put that file somewhere?

Answer (score 20):

### `django-debug-toolbar` 2.0

By default, [`django-debug-toolbar`](https://pypi.org/project/django-debug-toolbar/) 2.0 includes [`'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingPanel'`](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/panels.html#profiling) in the settings `DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS`. You can view this profiling information by ticking the "Profiling" checkbox in the toolbar and refreshing the page.

#### Old versions of `django-debug-toolbar`:

You can try the profiling panel of the django-debug-toolbar (make sure you use the application's latest version from [github](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar)). Enable the panel like so in your settings.py:

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = (
  'debug_toolbar.panels.version.VersionDebugPanel',
  'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerDebugPanel',
  'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingDebugPanel',
)
```

This existence of this panel is not documented on the readme of django-debug-toolbar; that's why I answer here in the first place.

Comment: N.B. If you're using Debian or Ubuntu you'll also need to `apt-get install python-profiler` to get the `profile` and `pstats` modules as these have non-free licenses (thanks to Disney).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend writing some integration tests instead, or at least using the built in testing client to automate requests and put lots of debugging statements in the views

Django has a built in testing client:

```
from django.test.client import Client
c = Client()
response = c.post('/slow_url/')
```

And then in your view:

```
def slow_url(request):
    start = time.time()
    print 'Started db query'
    result = SomeComplexModel.objects.all()
    print 'Finished db query, took ', time.time() - start
    return render('some_complex_template.html', {'result': result})
```

Automating the process of making requests and being able to replicate them again and again while you make small changes is how you will improve your code. CPU time can be worked out if you measure the time it takes to run each function. It won't take you long to hone in on the part that is actually chewing up resources.

Comment: That is an obvious approach, but doesn't seems practical.

Comment: Since I looking for a profiling tool, I can always do this manually !

Comment: If you don't already write any unit or integration tests then you should really consider starting...

Comment: That's fine, I know the significance of Test - But that is not the answer to my question. I already have tests, but if I have to put timestamps temporarily then I can do that in my views.

Answer (score 2):

It's not profiling , but i generally simply use a view to calculate the execution time , it works also for views that 
need user login, it displays execution time in a simple page

```
 def test(request):
     from django.test.client import Client
     import time

     c = Client()

     #client login if needed
     response = c.post('/login/', {'username': 'admin', 'password': 'password'})

     start = time.time()
     response = c.get('/pagetotest/')

     #print response
     #print 'Finished, time: ', time.time() - start # output to console
     end=time.time() - start
     return render(request,'loadingtime.html',{'time':end})
```

it's a good start i think , hope it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

[django-silk](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk) can help.

- Install it with: `pip install django-silk`
- Add it in `settings.py`:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware',
    ...
]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'silk'
)
```

- Add the route in `urls.py`:

```sh
urlpatterns += [url(r'^silk/', include('silk.urls', namespace='silk'))]
```

- Finally, create the adequate tables in the database with:

```sh
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

You can then browse in your internet browser to `/silk` to find the page requested there.