# Debugging slow Django Admin views

Tags: python, django

Some of my views in Django Admin take too long to load up.
What is the best way to debug a Django Admin view to see what is chewing up cycles?

Comment: https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar#readme

Comment: you can try add `list_select_related = True` property to given admin class

Answer (score 9):

As rantanplan commented, [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) is the easiest way to start profiling (shows all queries executed on page load, their EXPLAIN, their time taken to execute, etc). You could also have a look at a question regarding profiling a slow django installation here:
[How to profile django application with respect to execution time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799982/how-to-profile-django-application-with-respect-to-execution-time)

That question mentions the use of hotshot, which is also referenced on Django's Wiki under [profiling django](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango).

Answer (score 5):

I too have seen this with particular models in the Django Admin if their tables are very, very large (several million records will do the trick) and the table engine is MySQL's InnoDB. It took me a while to figure out workarounds to get my Django admin humming again for tables with 100M+ records. The root problem ended up being expensive `COUNT(*)` queries on page load and also poorly constructed searching queries whenever I used one of my `search_fields` from the ModelAdmin.

I documented all my solutions here, so that they might one day help a fellow Django-er in distress: http://craiglabenz.me/2013/06/12/how-i-made-django-admin-scale/

Comment: Um, you should summarize/give the solution here in case the link breaks (again).

Comment: This answer worked, bug remember that if you are customing `ModelAdmin`, you should rewrite your `get_queryset` because `django.admin` use the `_default_manager`. More info check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545067/django-specify-which-model-manager-django-admin-should-use).

Answer (score 1):

If you use Django with MySQL then there is a bug in MySQL with INNER JOINs optimization. If you try to use foreign keys in `Admin.list_display` Django will generate query with ordering and INNER JOINs which are extremely slow in MySQL.

There are two solutions to that:

1. Use django-mysql-fix backend: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mysql-fix
2. Override `get_query_set` in AdminChangeList - remove `select_related` and set `prefetch_related` fields - more details are in my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23097385/1178806

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good answers regarding slow edit forms caused by ForeignKey tables with many records
[Django admin change form load quite slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755312/django-admin-change-form-load-quite-slow)

Regarding List Views:
1) You can add list_per_page option and show less results:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 20
```

2) Or use select_related():

2.1) For django < 1.6:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(EventAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.select_related('foreign_key_field1, foreign_key_field2, etc')
```

2.2) For django >= 1.6:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(EventAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.select_related('foreign_key_field1, foreign_key_field2, etc')
```

Of course, replace foreign_key_field1, and foreign_key_field2, etc with appropriate field names.