# Django admin change form load quite slow

Tags: python, django, performance, django-models, django-admin

One of my Django websites has following database models:
In Django App “common”:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True)
    _short_name = models.CharField(db_column="short_name", max_length = 32, blank=True)

class Particle(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Collection)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In Django App “sitcom”:

```
class Media(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 248)
    _short_name = models.CharField(db_column="short_name", max_length = 32, blank=True)
    capital = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    progress = models.CharField(max_length = 32, blank=True, null=True)

class Relation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    _short_name = models.CharField(db_column="short_name", max_length = 32, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    particle = models.ForeignKey(Particle, blank=True, null=True)
    media = models.ForeignKey(Media, blank=True, null=True)
```

In short, model class Relation has 3 foreign keys to other tables. 
The problem is, when I use Django Admin to change a single Relation, the page (change_form) loads rather slowly.
Later, I changed model class Relation as following:

```
class Relation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    _short_name = models.CharField(db_column="short_name", max_length = 32, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    particle_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    media_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The modification changed Foreign Keys to IntegerFields, so it disabled some of the magics inside Django ORM system, and now the change form page loads really fast.
My question is, what is the “disabled magics inside django orm”?  what has the potential to cause the problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not the magic of django Orm. It is magic of Form.
When you create a Foreign key in Model, then in ModelForm, a ModelChoiceField creates which has all choices of ForeignKey Model. And django Admin use all the properties of Form to create HTML. 
So use this code.

```
from django import forms
class RelationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    parent = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                              choices=Relation.objects.values_list('id', 'name'))
    particle = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                              choices=Particle.objects.values_list('id', 'content'))
    media = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                              choices=Media.objects.values_list('id', 'name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Relation
```

In Admis Site

```
from django.contrib import admin
class RelationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = RelationForm
    model = Relation
```

You can also cache the choices pass in a form.

Comment: thanks very much! it works, and now i can use ForeignKey again, it's much more convenience.

Answer (score 44):

In admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

class RelationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       raw_id_fields = ('Media','Particle',)

admin.site.register(Relation, RelationAdmin)
```

This brings up a nice little UI element in the form and considerably improves performance since it doesn't have to load a huge number of options in the select box.

Comment: Thanks! This little tip makes my admin site so much more usable!

Comment: sometimes you don'te ven want to edit the fields in the admin forms, just view them, you can also add  the `readonly_fields = ('Media','Particle',)`

Comment: This is amazing!

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) for `raw_id_fields`

Answer (score 12):

I'm willing to bet the issue is due to your `ForeignKey`. By default, django renders a `<select>` element for every foreign key.

If you have thousands of rows, this easily starts to bloat your HTML / DOM and I've noticed browsers starting to crap out at 20k items rendered in a `<select>` tag.

To fix it, look into overriding your admin form and not using the default widgets.

Answer (score 3):

Django now has support for [autocomplete_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) which uses Select2 for input. You can configure as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class RelationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       autocomplete_fields = ('Media','Particle',)

admin.site.register(Relation, RelationAdmin)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2022

Answer (score 1):

In my case the slowness was caused primarily by the outdated `django-debug-toolbar` (v1.7). `debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware` would cause the admin page to literally take 20 minutes to load if it contained a ForeignKey field with a couple hundred choices. Upgrading the toolbar to v1.8 solved everything. Maybe this helps someone.

Comment: This happened on a custom form (non-admin), and this was the fix for me. The "Templates" section of the toolbar seems to be the main culprit. I couldn't figure out why <100 FK choices were slaughtering the page loading times, and sure enough, DJDT v1.7 is the distribution I had in this particular package...

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

As mentioned by @yuji-tomita-tomita [elsewhere on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16756511), the admin `change_form` renders a `<select>` element for a `ForeignKey` field.

This is done using the `Select` [widget](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/widgets.py#L669).

By default, each `<option>` in the `<select>` element has a text label which is based on the `__str__()` method for the model that the `ForeignKey` points to. This can be seen in the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/models.py#L1213) for `forms.models.ModelChoiceField`.

So, if your `Model.__str__()` method uses *related fields*, you'll get additional database queries when the admin form populates the select options.

For example, based on the OP, suppose we would have this:

```
class Particle(models.Model):
    ...
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'particle owned by {}'.format(self.owner.name)
```

Then the admin would need to query the database to get the related `Collection.name` value for each `Particle` option.

The admin does *not* do this efficiently.

If you have many `Particle` objects, that can become very expensive very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If a ForeignKey Model has too many records it might freeze your edit form.
The best way to start, is to limit the fields that should be displayed on the form and gradually/one-by-one add other fields, checking which field makes the form slow.

```
from django.contrib import admin
class RelationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       fields = ('name',)
admin.site.register(Relation, RelationAdmin)
```

Then after adding a field that causes the problem, e.g. Media, the form would freeze again. Therefore, if you still need this field on the form you can use Vishal Shah's answer with raw_id_fields = ('Media', )