# Slow Django Admin change view

Tags: django

I've a model with approximately 150K rows.

- It takes 1.3s to render the ListView for this model.
- When I click the change link in the ListView I takes **almost 2 minutes** to render the change view.
- Other models have normal render times for the edit view.

Any ideas how to speed this up?

Comment: If you do not need the 150 rows however, it might be better to just *paginate* the admin view.

Comment: Hi Willem,
The problem is not the ListView, but the change_view and that is just the change for one row.

Comment: Try running the SQL to view an individual record directly in the databases and see how long that takes (select * ... where id="some_id"). Also, confirm that there's an index on the primary key, which Django should create by default.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to limit the number of returned rows and implement some type of pagination in your application.

Django conveniently implements a type of [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view)

Comment: I'm sorry. The problem is not listing the rows (ListView) but rendering the change of a row. In other words rendering the change_view. For example: ../record/5c4de557-793c-44e3-8af6-fc77bc0f6e8a/change/

Comment: If a ForeignKey Model has too many records it might freeze your edit form. Maybe you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755312/django-admin-change-form-load-quite-slow

Comment: That was it! The form was listing more than 10.000 rows in a selectbox as a foreign key field. Thanx!

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ask yourself **these questions**:

Do you have much work with your data in templates?

Can I do this work in a backend and in a template only render it?

Do I use pagination?

As I know pagination in Django implemented with LIMIT and OFFSET sql statements, which work not so quickly when you're having many pages. In our projects, we wrote a row SQL for this purpose which works a little bit faster.

Also, you can install [**Django Debug Toolbar**](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which can show you what statements django ORM is executing and measure time.