# Slow loading Django Admin change/add

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm making a classic single view application, mapping multiple
datasources.

Django-admin is paginated so there's no impact when I view my list, the problem is when I want to change/add it is .

Using the debug-toolbar my queries look fine, I don't think they take a long time.

I tried to use a suggestion here [Django admin change form load quite slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755312/django-admin-change-form-load-quite-slow) and created a form, but this had no impact.

When is use `exclude = ['e_vehicle','e_product']` it's no surprise that add/change screens load instantly.

Any thoughts please

[image]

**model.py**

```
class Product_Mapping(Trackable):
    product_mapping_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)   
    s_product =  models.OneToOneField(sProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    e_fund_manager = models.ForeignKey(eManager, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    e_product = models.ForeignKey(eProduct, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    e_vehicle = models.ForeignKey(eVehicle, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

eManager has around 3K

eProduct has around 17K (has fkey to eManager)

eVehicle has around 25K (has fkey to eProduct)

**form.py**

```
class MappingProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    s_product = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                            choices=sProduct.objects.values_list('final_publications_product_id', 'product_name'))
    e_fund_manager = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                            choices=eManager.objects.values_list('e_fund_manager_id', 'manager_name'))
    e_product = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                            choices=eProduct.objects.values_list('e_product_id', 'product_name'))
    e_vehicle = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                            choices=eVehicle.objects.values_list('e_vehicle_id', 'formal_vehicle_name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Product_Mapping
        fields = '__all__'
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Product_Mapping)
class ChampProductMappingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    form = MappingProductForm
```

Comment: Did you try using [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) for those 2 foreign keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be seen that there are too many values in `e_product` and `e_vehicle` tables. You are using `ChoiceField` it means inside HTML dropdown there would be ~17K-25K options this would slow down rendering and sometimes hang on client side.

**Solution**

edit your **forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import ForeignKeyRawIdWidget

class MappingProductForm(forms.ModelForm):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MappingProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        rel_model = self.Meta.model
        rel_eprod = rel_model._meta.get_field('e_product').rel
        rel_eprod = rel_model._meta.get_field('e_vehicle').rel
        self.fields['e_product'].widget = ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(rel_eprod, admin_site=admin.site)
        self.fields['e_vehicle'].widget = ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(rel_eprod, admin_site=admin.site)

    s_product = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                            choices=sProduct.objects.values_list('final_publications_product_id', 'product_name'))
    e_fund_manager = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                            choices=eManager.objects.values_list('e_fund_manager_id', 'manager_name'))
    e_product = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False,
                            choices=eProduct.objects.all())
    e_vehicle = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False,
                            choices=eVehicle.objects.all()
                            )

    class Meta:
        model = Product_Mapping
        fields = '__all__'
```

This would keep raw id as widget. You can get something like below.

[image]

You can add other entries by hitting search button besides input.

This is better option when you have lots of choices in `ModelChoiceField`

Comment: I know this is a separate question but related, is there a way to load a different form for add vs change?

Comment: Yes It is possible! You may check `_changeform_view()` method and `add_view()` of `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin` class. Yet, this is not better place to write big answers :)