# How load foreingkey in admin site Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to change the way to load models on the admin page, especially foreign keys, because I have a delay to load them, the option for this was to exclude the field, but I want to have another option, thanks

```py
# model.service.py
class Service(BaseModel):
    # Service data
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Any = models.CharField()...


# service_form.py

class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Service
        exclude = ["client"]


# admin.py

class serviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = models.service

admin.site.register(models.service, ServiceAdmin)
```

this way I exclude the field for loading, but is there a way to do it that doesn't take so long to load?

Comment: Try doing the `exclude` in your serviceAdmin class.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimization your admin page with following attributes:

```
class serviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    autocomplete_fields = ('client',) 
    list_select_related = ('client',)
```

more info: [autocomplete_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) , [list_select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related)

Answer (score 0):

"""

class AdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = [
"id", "client"
]
raw_id_fields = ('client',)

"""

With raw_id_fields, this change provides the load of admin site, take of this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755312/django-admin-change-form-load-quite-slow)