# Ajax call time to load in django application

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am developing a django app using the Django Rest Framework with chart.JS in order to render some chart.

My ajax call is taking a long long long time and I am on local.. 
Is there a way to check what is taking so long in order to know where to look in order to refactor ?

it takes on average on local between 10 and 15 second each time.. 
Here is my code for example:

```
<script>
var endpoint = 'api/chart/data2'
$('.ajaxProgress').show();
$('.dashboard-container').hide();
function getAvg(grades) {
  return grades.reduce(function (p, c) {
    return p + c;
  }) / grades.length;
}
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: endpoint,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
    complete_data = data.team_complete,
    info_data = data.team_info_score,
    motiv_data = data.team_motiv_score,
    action_data = data.team_action_score,
    behaviour_data = data.team_behaviour_score,
    user_list = data.users,
    user_dist = data.user_dist,
    info_dist = data.info_dist,
    motiv_dist = data.motiv_dist,
    action_dist  = data.action_dist,
    behav_dist = data.behav_dist,
    info_label = data.info_label,
    motivation_label = data.motivation_label,
    action_label = data.action_label,
    behav_label = data.behav_label,
    complete_label = data.complete_label,
    cohesiveness_score = data.cohesiveness_score

    var bar_color = [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 220, 89, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 192, 35, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 220, 89, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 192, 35, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
    ]
    var ctx = document.getElementById("mainGraph").getContext('2d');
    var ctx2 = document.getElementById("mainGraph2").getContext('2d');
    var ctx3 = document.getElementById("mainGraphLine1").getContext('2d');
    var ctx4 = document.getElementById("mainGraphLine2").getContext('2d');
    var ctx5 = document.getElementById("mainGraphLine3").getContext('2d');
    var ctx6 = document.getElementById("mainGraphLine4").getContext('2d');
    $('.ajaxProgress').hide();
    $('.dashboard-container').show();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mainGraph");
    var mainGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: complete_label,
            datasets: [{
                data: complete_data,
                backgroundColor: bar_color ,

            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                display: false
            },
            responsive:true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                ticks: {autoSkip: false}
                     }]
                    }
                 },
    });
    //end graph 1//
    canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
      var activePoints = mainGraph.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
      if (activePoints[0]) {
        var chartData = activePoints[0]['_chart'].config.data;
        var idx = activePoints[0]['_index'];

        var label = chartData.labels[idx];
        var str_label = label.toString()
        console.log(str_label)
        var value = chartData.datasets[0].data[idx];
        if(label == "General,Details"){
          $('#general').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Sameness,Difference"){
          $('#sameness').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Visual,Auditory"){
          $('#visual').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Static,Process"){
          $('#static').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Best Scenario,Worst Scenario"){
          $('#bestScenario').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Binary,Shades"){
          $('#binary').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "External,Internal"){
          $('#external').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Go Away,Toward"){
          $('#goAway').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Things"){
          $('#things').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Variety,Routine"){
          $('#variety').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Active,Reaction"){
          $('#active').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Manager worker"){
          $('#manager').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Option,Procedure"){
          $('#option').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Perfection,Optimizing"){
          $('#perfection').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Sensor,Intuition"){
          $('#sensor').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "External locus,Internal locus"){
          $('#locus').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "Strong Will,Compliant"){
          $('#will').modal('show');
        } else if(label == "In time,Through time"){
          $('#time').modal('show');
        } else{
          $('#modeling').modal('show');
        }
    }}
    ;

    //graph 2 //
    var mainGraph2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            labels: user_list,
            datasets: [{
                data: user_dist,
                backgroundColor: bar_color ,

            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                display: false
            },
            responsive:true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                ticks: {autoSkip: false,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        min: 0,
                        max:100,
                        }
              }]
            },
            annotation: {
              annotations: [
                        {
                          type: "line",
                          mode: "vertical",
                          scaleID: "x-axis-0",
                          value: getAvg(user_dist),
                          borderColor: "rgba(216, 138, 138, 1)",
                          label: {
                            content: "AVERAGE",
                            fontFamily:'Ubuntu',
                            enabled: true,
                            position: "middle",
                            fontSize: 10,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                 },
    });
    //end graph 2//

    //graph 3 //
    var mainGraphLine1 = new Chart(ctx3, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: info_label,
            datasets: [{
                data: info_dist,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.2)' ,

            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                display: false
            },
            responsive:true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                ticks: {autoSkip: false,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        }
              }],
              yAxes: [{
              ticks: {min: 0, max:100}
            }],
            },
            annotation: {
              annotations: [
                        {
                          type: "line",
                          mode: "horizontal",
                          scaleID: "y-axis-0",
                          value: getAvg(info_dist),
                          borderColor: "rgba(216, 138, 138, 1)",
                          borderWidth: 0.5,
                          label: {
                            content: "AVERAGE",
                            fontFamily:'Ubuntu',
                            enabled: true,
                            position: "middle",
                            fontSize: 8,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                 },
    });
    //end graph 3//

    //graph 4 //
    var mainGraphLine2 = new Chart(ctx4, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: motivation_label,
            datasets: [{
                data: motiv_dist,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.2)' ,

            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                display: false
            },
            responsive:true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                ticks: {autoSkip: false,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        }
              }],
              yAxes: [{
              ticks: {min: 0, max:100}
            }],
            },
            annotation: {
              annotations: [
                        {
                          type: "line",
                          mode: "horizontal",
                          scaleID: "y-axis-0",
                          value: getAvg(motiv_dist),
                          borderColor: "rgba(216, 138, 138, 1)",
                          borderWidth: 0.5,
                          label: {
                            content: "AVERAGE",
                            fontFamily:'Ubuntu',
                            enabled: true,
                            position: "middle",
                            fontSize: 8,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                 },
    });
    //end graph 4//
    //graph 5 //
    var mainGraphLine3 = new Chart(ctx5, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: action_label,
            datasets: [{
                data: action_dist,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.2)' ,

            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                display: false
            },
            responsive:true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                ticks: {autoSkip: false,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        }
              }],
              yAxes: [{
              ticks: {min: 0, max:100}
            }],
            },
            annotation: {
              annotations: [
                        {
                          type: "line",
                          mode: "horizontal",
                          scaleID: "y-axis-0",
                          value: getAvg(action_dist),
                          borderColor: "rgba(216, 138, 138, 1)",
                          borderWidth: 0.5,
                          label: {
                            content: "AVERAGE",
                            fontFamily:'Ubuntu',
                            enabled: true,
                            position: "middle",
                            fontSize: 8,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                 },
    });
    //end graph 5//

    //graph 6 //
    var mainGraphLine4 = new Chart(ctx6, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: behav_label,
            datasets: [{
                data:behav_dist,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.2)',

            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                display: false
            },
            responsive:true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                ticks: {autoSkip: false,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        }
              }],
              yAxes: [{
                ticks: {min: 0, max:100}
            }],
            },
            annotation: {
              annotations: [
                        {
                          type: "line",
                          mode: "horizontal",
                          scaleID: "y-axis-0",
                          value: getAvg(behav_dist),
                          borderColor: "rgba(216, 138, 138, 0.8)",
                          borderWidth: 0.5,
                          label: {
                            content: "AVERAGE",
                            fontFamily:'Ubuntu',
                            enabled: true,
                            position: "middle",
                            fontSize: 8,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                 },
    });
    //end graph 6//


}

})

</script>
```

Comment: Add `console.log(new Date().getTime());` as needed throughout your script

Comment: When I put it at the en of my javascript I get 1523268128733 in my console .. How do I use it exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can test you django api using postman. You will get the execution time there.

Also if you want to profile your django app you can refer the following link [profiling django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361985/profiling-django?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I tried POSTMAN now .. I can get can the overall time which is 13745 ms but I would like to know for each request in my API call.. is it possible ?

Comment: Then you have to profile your Django app. Check of there are multiple API calls or any other blocking I/o and try to parallelize them.