# Optimizing SimpleJWT to improve performance

Tags: python, django, authentication, jwt

I got a issue with SimpleJWT on my API built in Django, it takes 2 secs to response.
I know it doesn't seem like a long time but I really need to improve it.
On the Profile table in MySQL database, username and password fields are indexed.
I was reading the official documentation but I don't see any advice for improve performance.

Someone there with a better knowledge than me that who can help me?

settings.py

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=6000),
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,  
}
```

urls.py  (cutted)

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView)


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('api.urls')),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair')
]
```

I tried indexing the username and password fields on the Profile table.

Comment: How do you know the issue is with SimpleJWT? Did you profile your app? If not, that's where you should start: you won't be able to increase performance if you are trying to speed up the wrong thing. There are some tips in the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361985/profiling-django).